# how to report a missing relationship from the child side of a lookup with custom object?

Tags: reporting, lookup, child-to-parent

I have 2 custom objects:

Candidate & Worker

Candidate has a field that is a lookup called "Tech Screener:" and allows me to select any worker.

Lets say I have 10 candidate records. I also have 5 worker records, Sue, Joe, Bob, Jim, and Jen. Sue is the tech screener on 2 candidates, Bob is on 3, and Jim is on 5. However Joe and Jen have not been chosen as tech screener at all.

How do I write a report that shows workers who have not been selected in any candidate "tech screener" fields. (that will show Joe and Jen)

Its easy for me to get a report from the candidate side and group by tech screener, but I cant figure out how to go the other direction? Custom report type doesnt show "Tech Screener" as option when starting with workers.

Comment: Have you tried report cross-filter?